# Random product thumbnails

Tags: image, random

The shop page on my website displays the "full-length" image of a product, and then, on hover, a "close-up" image.

I wish to randomise this, so that for some products, the "close-up" is displayed on load, and for others, the "full-length". And to have this random with every page load.

"Full-length" images are always named xxx1.jpg, and "close-up" images are xxx2.jpg, e.g.

```
<li>
    <div id="product">
        <img class="full-length" src="/image-1.jpg"/>
        <img class="close-up" src="/image-2.jpg"/>
    </div>
</li>
```

I guess I need a random number generator, between 1 and 2, and then for the second image to be what the first image is *not*.

Any help, sincerely and very much obliged.

Comment: what you exactly you wanna you do?
want to show one image out of given images?
PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this can help you.Java script code is:

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
function onloadSetImage()
{
document.getElementById('product1').src='image-'+getRandomArbitrary(1,5);
}
```

html ([onload can check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)):

```
<body onload="onloadSetImage();"/>
<li>
  <img id="product1" src=""/>
</li>
</body>
```